# Generating function for the Hurwitz Zeta: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta_{H}(k+1,a)(-z)^{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form, zeta-functions

We know from the digamma function

$$ \Psi (z+1)= -\gamma -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta(k+1)(-z)^{k} $$

My question is if there is a similar formula for

$$ f(a)+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta_{H}(k+1,a)(-z)^{k}\quad?$$

Using Ramanujan's master theorem i would say that i should take the mellin inverse of

$$ \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}\zeta _{H} (1-s,a) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The considered generating function admits a closed form.

> **Proposition.** Let $a$ be a complex number such that $\Re a>0$. Then
>   $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta_{H}(k+1,a)(-z)^{k}=\psi(a)-\psi (a+z),\qquad |z|<|a|,
> $$ where $\psi:=\Gamma'/\Gamma$.

*Proof.* Let $a$ be a complex number such that $\Re a>0$ and let $z$ be a complex number satisfying $|z|<|a|$.

We have$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta_{H}(k+1,a)(-z)^{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+a)^{k+1}}\right)(-z)^{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(n+a)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{z}{(n+a)}\right)^{k}\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z}{(n+a)(n+a+z)}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z}{n(n+a-1)}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z}{n(n+a+z-1)}\\\\
&=\psi(a)-\psi (a+z)
\end{align}
$$ where we have used a standard [series representation (6.3.16)](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) for the digamma function.